# How to include hidden files in ls pattern match?

Tags: linux, bash

I was just trying to list files in the current directory with a certain pattern, but it doesn't work with hidden files. How can I match all the files?

I tried

```
ls *foo*
```

and

```
ls -a *foo*
```

Not finding anything in Google, the keywords I can think of to search for this lead to a lot of unrelated informations...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Enable globbing for hidden files:

```
shopt -s dotglob
ls *foo*
```

Disable:

```
shopt -u dotglob
```

Show globbing status:

```
shopt dotglob
```

Comment: For me, 'shopt dotglob' shows the current value, but 'shopt -p dotglob' doesn't (using bash on Mac OS X).