# How to get the largest 10 folders (not files or sub folders) in the current directory?

Tags: bash

I want to find the largest 10 folders in a current directory with human-readable folder size? The examples I've seen, all are listing files along with the folders. I just want to see which folders are using most spaces, because each folder is being used by different users.

Following is the code I tried

```
du -hs * | sort -rh | head -10
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide the code you have tried so far.

Comment: @Anaksunaman edited. Please check.

Comment: Change `*` to `*/` and it will match directories only. In any case it won't match names starting with a dot though.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thank you! It worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Globbing

`du -hs *` in your code contains bare `*` globbing pattern. Your shell expands it to filenames of almost all [files](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690) in the current directory, so in general `du` gets multiple arguments: directories and non-directories.

"Almost", because `*` doesn't match names starting with a dot (`.`). These are hidden. In Bash you can [change this behavior by invoking `shopt -s dotglob`](https://superuser.com/a/865963/432690).

To match directories only, append a trailing slash to the pattern:

```
du -hs */ | sort -rh | head -10
```

This simple solution will fail if there are too many directories. The error will be `argument list too long`.

---

#### `find`

A generic way to do something to files matching some criteria is `find`. A `find` command solving your case is more complicated than the above. I'm posting it here mainly as a starting point for users who want to add more criteria (especially criteria that cannot be easily included in the solution with `*/`):

```
find . -type d ! -name . -prune -exec du -hs {} + | sort -rh | head -10
```

It means: starting from `.` find all files of the type directory (`-type d`) that are not `.` (`! -name .`). Do not descend into them (`-prune`). Execute `du -hs` zero or more times, passing possibly multiple pathnames of found files to a single invocation of `du` (`-exec du … {} +`).

This solution won't trigger `argument list too long` because `find` is smart enough to run more than one `du`, if needed, so each `du` gets a list that is not too long. If you need a robust solution (e.g. in a script that should work without supervision) then prefer `find` over globbing.

---

#### `ncdu`

An interactive approach is [`ncdu`](https://superuser.com/a/1125862/432690). It's true it shows non-directories along with directories, but you can easily tell them apart (observe leading slashes) or toggle "dirs before [other] files when sorting" (<kbd>t</kbd>).